# PowerShell web request to fonts.googleapis.com result differs from browser request

Tags: powershell, fonts

I'm requesting a certain font from the google API using the PowerShell's `Invoke-WebRequest`.
But when I use the browser (chrome) to request the file's content it shows me an entirely different result.

I also tried immitating Chrome in PS request, but the result stays the same.

The font is located here https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500
and I used this command in PS:

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500' -OutFile ./roboto.css -UserAgent ([Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::Chrome)
```

Which gives me this file:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc-.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxM.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc-.woff) format('woff');
}
```

But in the browser this file gets displayed:

```css
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fABc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0301, U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCBc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBxc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCxc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fChc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc4.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0301, U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCRc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fABc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0301, U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCBc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBxc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Can somebody enlighten me as to why this happens?
Is this also happening on your end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing `[PSUserAgent]::Chrome` with the UA string from a recent version of Chrome appears to work:

```
$userAgentChrome104Windows10 = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500' -OutFile ./roboto.css -UserAgent $userAgentChrome104Windows10
```